# Installed base them NineSixty - where is it?

Tags: theming, installation

I've installed the base theme NineSixty using the URL method without any errors.
When I then look for the files I can't find them anywhere.
I've looked in the themes directory as well as the sites/all/themes directories. In fact i've looked everywhere.

Where do the base theme's files end up?

Comment: Should be in `/sites/all/themes`. If it isn't, you have a bit of a problem. Download archive manually, see what files are in it, and search your HDD for them.

Comment: You mean you installed and enabled it, and the theme is working but the files aren't there? Or do you mean you installed it but you can't enable the theme and can't find the files? If it's the latter, then the installation wasn't successful, check your file system for permission for the web server to write to that folder. Since you haven't stated what type of server/environment this problem is happening in, I'm assuming it's a linux server.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I'm using a 1and1.co.uk hosted linux based server.
The theme seems to have been installed ok as it appears in the themes list.
I've also created a basic sub-theme which uses ninesixty without any problems. It's the sub-theme that I've enabled. All fine so far.
The only confusing part is that i've FTP'ed to the server and can't see any of the ninesixty files there although they must be as i'm sub-theming from them?!

Comment: Terminal in and run `grep -nr ninesixty web_root_folder` from just below your web root...

Comment: Excellent, thanks! It seemed to be an FTP caching issue I think. Although I reconnected a few times and refreshed the view it still wasn't showing. Eventually it did as was where expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the database, check the "system" table of your drupal database and look for a record with the "name" ninesixty. That row will also tell you the path to the theme.

If you have phpmyadmin via cpanel or something similar you can just browse the system table.

Otherwise you could use this SQL (if your database is using a prefix it will be slightly different a the prefix will be appended to the table name "system"):

```
SELECT * FROM system WHERE name = 'ninesixty';
```

and that will give you all the info about your ninesixty theme.

Another way is to search your file system for the word ninesixty, which I imagine won't be anywhere except for the theme and maybe your base theme.

Comment: Thanks for the information rooby. Although the issue is now solved this is most helpful info. Out of interested do drupal document the DB schema?

Comment: I don't think so but I could be wrong.  You can either just look throught the database or you can look in module install files, which have database schemas related to the module.